# Find all sentences that end with one of strings in array with Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I'm looking for a way to filter strings that end with one value from an array in Kotlin.

```
fun findStringsThatEndWith(sentences: List<String>, value: String) = sentences
    .filter { it.endsWith(value) }
```

This will allow me to filter all sentences that end with one value.

But what I would like to do is:

```
fun findStringsThatEndWith(sentences: List<String>, vararg value: String) = sentences
    .filter { it.endsWith(value // This won't work //) }
```

And when I do this, I will have to know how many values the vararg will hold.

```
fun findStringsThatEndWith(sentences: List<String>, vararg value: String) = sentences
    .filter { it.endsWith(value[0]) || it.endsWith(value[1]) }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the lambda you pass to `filter` add a function that loops round the `value` parameter and checks each one, e.g.

```
fun findStringsThatEndWith(sentences: List<String>, vararg value: String) =
        sentences.filter { sentence -> value.any { sentence.endsWith(it) } }
```